# Ansible: create/concatenate list from individual items plus list from a variable

Tags: ansible, yaml

lets assume I have this:

```
list1:
 - "item1"
 - "item2"
```

And now I want to build another list by using the first one

```
list2:
 - "item3"
 - "item4"
 + "{{ list1 }}"
```

This doesn't work, what works is:

```
list2: "{{ ['item3', 'item4'] + list2 }}"
```

But I find it hard to read and hard to extend with new items like `item5` etc.

Is there a way I can create `list2` with something similar to the first version?

***** Update *****

The specific situation I want to create this list is in a `host_var` file, let's say in `host_var/my_server.yml`

Comment: Your question does not specify in which file (or ansible/jinja2 context) you are trying to accomplish that goal, since it matters. Please pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section of the how-to-ask guide

Answer (score 0):

You can use another var

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    list1:
      - "item1"
      - "item2"

    list2:
      - "item3"
      - "item4"

    list4: "{{ list1 | default([]) + list2 | default([]) + list3 | default([]) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ list4 }}"
```

And the output:

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3",
        "item4"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are right that it is better in terms of expandability. But I was hoping I could put everything in the definition of `list2`.